# LabelSpan not reducing in ResponsiveGridLayout - Label width issue in SAPUI5 Form layout

Tags: layout, frontend, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm facing an issue with the `LabelSpan` property in the `ResponsiveGridLayout` of a SAPUI5 application. I have a form layout with labels and input fields, but no matter how I adjust the `LabelSpan` property, the labels are not reducing in width as expected.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
<f:Form width="100%">
    <f:layout>
        <f:ResponsiveGridLayout columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" labelSpanXL="1" labelSpanL="1" emptySpanL="0" emptySpanM="0"
            singleContainerFullSize="false"/>
    </f:layout>
    <f:FormContainer>
        <f:FormElement>
            <Label text="{i18n>tooltip.label.plant}" />
            <Input id="configPlant" value="{newSample>/plant}" editable="false" textAlign="Center"/>
            <Label text="{i18n>tooltip.label.type}"/>
            <ComboBox id="adminSampleType" required="true" selectedKey="{newSample>/type}" change="onSampleTypeChange" filterSecondaryValues="true"
                valueStateText="{i18n>msg.error.validLayout}" items="{path: 'view>/types', sorter: {path: 'type', descending: true}}">
                <core:ListItem key="{view>type}" text="{view>description}"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </f:FormElement>
    </f:FormContainer>
    <!-- Other form elements -->
</f:Form>
```

I have tried adjusting the `LabelSpan` property with different values, but the labels remain wider than expected. How can I make the labels narrower without using CSS? Is there an alternative way to control the label width in `ResponsiveGridLayout`?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried to resolve the issue by adjusting the value of the `LabelSpan` property in the `ResponsiveGridLayout`. I attempted to modify the `labelSpanXL`, `labelSpanL`, and `labelSpanM` values to different values, but the labels in my form layout did not reduce their width as I expected.

Additionally, I attempted to apply formatting directly to the labels individually by setting the width property or adjusting the `LabelSpan` property directly on the labels, but these attempts also did not result in the desired outcome.

Despite these efforts, the labels in my form layout still occupy more space than I intended, and I am unable to achieve the desired narrower width for the labels without resorting to using CSS.

I am seeking alternative solutions or suggestions on how to control the label width in a `ResponsiveGridLayout` without resorting to CSS modifications. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.